# Solving power sequence including $1/x$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to solve the following weighted probability

$$ \sum_{x=1}^\infty \operatorname{Prob}(x \mid x > 0) \frac{1}{x} $$

where $\operatorname{Prob}(x)$ is Poisson with rate $\lambda$.

I can rewrite

\begin{align} &\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{\lambda^{x}}{x}}{x!} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}} \sum_{x=1}^\infty  \frac{\int_0^\lambda u^{x-1} \, du}{x!}  \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}\int_0^\lambda \sum_{x=1}^\infty  \frac{u^{x-1}}{x!} \, du = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}} \int_0^\lambda \frac{1}{u} \sum_{x=1}^\infty  \frac{u^{x}}{x!} \, du \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}\int_0^\lambda \frac{1}{u}(e^u - 1 )  \, du \\[8pt]
\end{align}

When integrated indefinitely, $\frac{e^u}{u} = Ei(u) + k$ (according to WolframAlpha). However, with the integration bounds, it doesnt give me an answer. How do I proceed?

Comment: WolframAlpha has [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+lambda^x%2F%28x*x!%29+for+x+%3D+1+to+infinity) to say.

Comment: A second thought: I haven't looked closely at your derivation, but I'd be wary of using indefinite integrals for their specific value, since they are unique only up to a constant difference.

Comment: As what Brian commented, you may try something like $\frac {\lambda^x} {x} = \int_0^{\lambda} u^{x-1}du$ instead. But I have not test the later part of the computation.